# Webpack not converting ES6 to ES5

Tags: node.js, webpack, babeljs

I'm very new to Webpack. I think I'm doing it incorrectly. I would like to convert an ES6 function to ES5 function using babel. So I did some research and I found babel-loader. However, I'm not sure what I'm doing.

I ran npm install babel-loader --save-dev and it got added into my package.json

// package.json

```
{
  "name": "kanban",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "kanban",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.3.21",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^1.7.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "webpack": "^1.12.9"
  }
}
```

// webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');
var HtmlwebpackPlugin =  require('html-webpack-plugin');

const PATHS = {
  app: path.join(__dirname, 'app'),
  build: path.join(__dirname, 'build')
};

module.exports = {
  entry: PATHS.app,
  output: {
    path: PATHS.build,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlwebpackPlugin({
      title: 'Kanban app'
    })
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader' }
    ]
  }
};
```

// app/index.js - I just added some random useless function in ES6 syntax. I was hoping I'll see the ES5 format in my bundle.js file but it didn't change. It's still ES6 syntax in bundle.js

```
var component = require('./component');
var app = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild('app');
app.appendChild(component());

let myJson = {
  prop: 'myProp'
};

let fives = [];
nums = [1, 2, 5, 15, 25, 32];

// Statement bodies
nums.forEach(function (v) {
  if (v % 5 === 0) {
    fives.push(v);
  }
}, this);

console.log(fives);

let sum = (a, b) => a + b;
```

// app/component.js

```
module.exports = function() {
  var element = document.createElement('h1');
  element.innerHTML = 'hello world';
  return element;
};
```

Comment: What do you expect it would do? You must compile your script with babel in the console or in a task runner (grunt, gulp, ...). https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/

Comment: Thanks a lot. I thought Webpack will do it for me via babel-loader.

Comment: What I would like to happen is for Webpack to call babel and as much as possible to not use grunt or gulp

Comment: I found this in 2 seconds on google all you need. Please search a little bit before asking! http://www.2ality.com/2015/04/webpack-es6.html

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't sure which terminologies to search for. That helped me a lot

Comment: Ludo, when i did a search, this S.O. question is what came up.  And I'm glad it did because i got exactly the answer I was looking for (thanks, @dreyescat) without my having to search through full page tutorials like the one you linked to (which, while sometimes great also sometimes don't have the specific answer I need).  Everyone learns in different ways, and for me, Stack Overflow is often my preferred way to get a quick answer.  So I'm glad OP asked the question.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you want to compile ES6 to ES5 you need to install Babel [ES2015 preset](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2015/).

```
npm install babel-preset-es2015
```

Then you need to enable this preset. One way to enable this ES6 to ES5 compilation is using [babel-loader](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader#options) query string:

```
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader?presets[]=es2015'
      }
    ]
  }
```

or query option:

```
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015']
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try it once I get home. I keep getting disconnected from the network.

Comment: It worked using this loader configuration
      module: {
        loaders: [
           {
              loader: 'babel-loader',
              test: path.join(__dirname, 'app'),
              query: {
                presets: 'es2015',
              }
            }
        ]
      }

Comment: This seems to have no effect.  Still emitting ES6 code.

Comment: This actually doesn't work.  Preset 'es2015' does nothing at all, everything is installed properly.

Comment: ES6 stands for the version released in 2015(ES2015).  ES5.1 stands for the version released in 2011. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#Versions

Comment: Why the value `ES2015` targets even ES5:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34747693/how-do-i-get-babel-6-to-compile-to-es5-javascript#comments-34747852

Comment: ECMAScript 5 is also known as ES5 and ECMAScript 2009. ES2015 != ES5

Comment: Reminder: this likely wont work for your version today. Read this answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59328252/5281187

Comment: Question should be updated to reflect the latest versions/standards. Also an explanation of the differences between multiple methods shown would be helpful.

Answer (score 20):

babel-preset-es2015 is deprecated. Try:

```
npm install -D babel-loader @babel/core @babel/preset-env webpack
```

then in your webpack.config.js :

```
{
  test: /\.m?js$/,
  exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
  use: {
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    options: {
      presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
    }
  }
}
```

[more info](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/babel-loader/)

Comment: Confirmed this works for the modern installations of webpack. Check your projects version.

Comment: Yes it's has been deprecated. When I do npm install babel-preset-es2015 now, it note me that : deprecated babel-preset-es2015@6.24.1: ????  Thanks for using Babel: we recommend using babel-preset-env now: please read https://babeljs.io/env to update!

And I got following code in .babelrc file now, it is works as expected:
{
    "presets":["env", "react"]
}

Answer (score 15):

for webpack 3, the module options should look like

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
       use: {
          loader:'babel-loader',
          options: { presets: ['es2015'] }
       },
       test: /\.js$/,
       exclude: /node_modules/
    }
  ]
},
```

this still requires `babel-loader` and `babel-preset-es2015`

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem. The official React answer is to add this configuration to Webpack.

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react", "stage-0"],
  "plugins": ["react-hot-loader/babel"]
}
```

Here is the link: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/8379

Answer (score 0):

you should also add `target: "es5"` in `webpack.config.js`

```js
...

module.exports = {
  ...
  module: {
    target: "es5", // add this
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader' }
    ]
  }
};
```

see details at https://stackoverflow.com/a/65376531/10691147