# Import into a vue.js component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to import a library of the [Vuelidate](https://vuelidate.netlify.com/) plugin into my **newsletter.vue.js** component.

But this import returns an error: **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier**

How can I import this into my vue.js component?

First to all, **I´m using webpack and call first Vuelidate**:

```
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

require('./bootstrap');


window.Vue = require('vue');

import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
import Vuelidate from 'vuelidate'

Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
Vue.use(Vuelidate)

/**
 * The following block of code may be used to automatically register your
 * Vue components. It will recursively scan this directory for the Vue
 * components and automatically register them with their "basename".
 *
 * Eg. ./components/ExampleComponent.vue -> <example-component></example-component>
 */

// const files = require.context('./', true, /\.vue$/i)
// files.keys().map(key => Vue.component(key.split('/').pop().split('.')[0], files(key).default))

//Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

const app = new Vue({
});

window.onload = function(){
    app.$mount('#app');
}
```

Then I see that I have to import 'vuelidate/lib/validators' into the component in order to use it.

Like [this example](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/reference/validation/).

The problem is that I can't do an import inside my component vue, it always gives me error.

This is the code of my component:

```
import validators from 'vuelidate/lib/validators';//this return me error

Vue.component('newsletter', {

    template :  '<div>\
      <b-form @submit="onSubmit">\
        \
          \
        <b-form-group id="exampleInputGroup2" label="Food" label-for="exampleInput2">\
          <b-form-select\
            id="exampleInput2"\
            :options="foods"\
            :state="$v.form.food.$dirty ? !$v.name.$error : null"\
            v-model="form.food"\
          />\
  \
          <b-form-invalid-feedback id="input2LiveFeedback">\
            This is a required field\
          </b-form-invalid-feedback>\
        </b-form-group>\
  \
        <b-button type="submit" variant="primary" :disabled="$v.form.$invalid">Submit</b-button>\
      </b-form>\
    </div>',

    props : ['route_post'],

    data: function()
    {
        return {
            foods: ['apple', 'orange'],
            form: {}
          }
    },  

    validations: {
      form: {
        name: {
          required: validators.required,
          minLength: validators.minLength(3)
        }
      }
    },

});
```

Comment: Off-topic but please use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) rather than double or single quotes for your template strings as they [support newline characters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Multi-line_strings).

Comment: Do you use webpack? Imports do not work without proper setup. Have you used Vue CLI to setup the project?

Answer (score 1):

The error you got is as a result of not correctly importing what you want to use. There are several ways to import this library.

Import and use globally:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuelidate from 'vuelidate'
Vue.use(Vuelidate)
```

Alternatively, import a mixin directly to components:

```
import { validationMixin } from 'vuelidate'

var Component = Vue.extend({
  mixins: [validationMixin],
  validations: { ... }
})
```

Or

```
import { required, maxLength } from 'vuelidate/lib/validators'
```

Or import them individually to reduce import size:

```
import required from 'vuelidate/lib/validators/required'
import maxLength from 'vuelidate/lib/validators/maxLength'
```

You could also use `require`:

```
const { required, minLength } = require('vuelidate/lib/validators')
```

For your use case, `validators` doesn't exist in `'vuelidate/lib/validators'` as it is not a property/member.

**Update:**
From the Bootstrap example link you provided, it is possible an older version of vuelidate.

Vuelidate does not provide a default export hence this import style `import validators from 'vuelidate/lib/validators'` doesn't work. Using named imports on the other hand works just fine.

Comment: Can you create a sandbox and I will have a look at it?

Comment: Please create a sandbox at codesandbox.io so I can look into what you're doing wrong. The code you have in the question is not sufficient.

Comment: It's laravel 5.7 with its stack of webpack and vuejs, it's impossible to create a sandbox that simulates it.

Comment: Create just the Vue part that you want to have Vuelidate for.

Answer (score 0):

You first have to add it to your app like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuelidate from 'vuelidate'
Vue.use(Vuelidate)
```

Then, you can use it by destructuring, like this:

```
import { validators } from 'vuelidate'
```

Comment: I have webpack with a app.js file and this instructions: import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
import Vuelidate from 'vuelidate'

Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
Vue.use(Vuelidate)

Answer (score 0):

**ES6**

Use named import and change the validations section as follows:

```
import { validators, minLength } from 'vuelidate/lib/validators';

Vue.component('newsletter', {

    template :  `<div>
      <b-form @submit="onSubmit">
        <b-form-group id="exampleInputGroup2" label="Food" label-for="exampleInput2">
          <b-form-select
            id="exampleInput2"
            :options="foods"
            :state="$v.form.food.$dirty ? !$v.name.$error : null"
            v-model="form.food"
          />
          <b-form-invalid-feedback id="input2LiveFeedback">
            This is a required field
          </b-form-invalid-feedback>
        </b-form-group>
        <b-button type="submit" variant="primary" :disabled="$v.form.$invalid">Submit</b-button>
      </b-form>
    </div>`,

    props : ['route_post'],

    data: function()
    {
        return {
            foods: ['apple', 'orange'],
            form: {}
          }
    },  

    validations: {
      form: {
        name: {
          required,
          minLength: minLength(3)
        }
      }
    },

});
```

Comment: import { validators } from 'vuelidate/lib/validators'; return me this error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Comment: Weird. it is a [general es6 syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Import_a_single_export_from_a_module). Is your environment ES6 compatible?

Comment: ES5 equivalent for `import myModule from './myModule';` is sth like `var myModule = require('./myModule');`.

Comment: Or, you make use of Babel like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34747693/how-do-i-get-babel-6-to-compile-to-es5-javascript

Answer (score 0):

First off, check in your node_modules if you have installed `vuelidate` at all:

`npm install vuelidate --save`

validators doesn't have exports default, you need to use destructuring to import each validation separately:

```
import { required, minLength } from 'vuelidate/lib/validators'; 

Vue.component('newsletter', {

... 
validations: {
name: {
  required,
  minLength: minLength(3)
},
```

Comment: import validators from 'vuelidate/lib/validators';//this continues return me error

Comment: @AntonioMorales, I have edited, looks like it doesn't find the 'vuelidate/lib/validators' so try with `const validators = require('vuelidate/lib/validators')`

Comment: @AntonioMorales in addition to my answer, I have added note at the top, since I have doubts that you have installed vuelidate?

Comment: If I use require: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Comment: @AntonioMorales, but did you installed node module at all?

Comment: Of course, I can call the $v object of Vuelidate, but I need to import the validators :(

Comment: @AntonioMorales, it looks like validators doesn't have exports default in index.js, but separate validations exported each. so you need to use destructuring in this case in order to use validation. Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Are you using vscode and vetur? Not sure if we encountered the same problem. But how I solved my problem was adding a jsconfig.json file on my root project folder and putting this code inside.

```
 {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    // This is the line you want to add
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/node_modules/*"]
 }
```

I think the import problem was due to vscode and intellisense. Does not have anything to do with vuelidate.

After you create your jsconfig and save it...restart vscode.