# angular azure app configuration giving SCRIPT1002: Syntax error in IE11

Tags: javascript, angular9, azure-app-configuration

this is the line in IE11 console
vendor.js (65816,1);

```
class AppConfigCredential {
constructor(credential, secret) {
    this.credential = credential;
    this.secret = secret;
}
```

Iam trying read the feature flags from azure appconfiguration from angular
it's working fine for all the browsers except in IE11
i tried replacing polyfiles and by adding tsconfig-es5.app and changing in angular json as required but no use and calling function is.

```
enter code here
async GetFeatureToggleValue(key: any) {
   const client = new AppConfigurationClient(this.AppconfigURL);;
   return await client.getConfigurationSetting({ key: 
   ".appconfig.featureflag/" + key }, { onlyIfChanged: true }); }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `class` keyword was introduced in ES2015/ES6.
Internet Explorer 11 does not support **ES6** and later versions of JavaScript.
(Chrome is currently at ES12).

You can use [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34747693/how-do-i-get-babel-6-to-compile-to-es5-javascript) to use **babel** to *transpile* your code to ES5.

However, if possible try to avoid developing for IE11 itself, as it will be removed from Windows 10 in June 2022. (source: [blog.windows.com](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2021/05/19/the-future-of-internet-explorer-on-windows-10-is-in-microsoft-edge/))