# How to assign Object assign and map function together in IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have sample code that works fine in Chrome but IE11 has problem because of Object.assign method and => sign.

Here is my code below and I don't know how to design it for IE11:

```
 let dictionary = Object.assign({}, ...tempGroups[tempKey].map((x) => ({ [x.ID]: x.Value })));
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: You use babel compiler to convert code in ES5 try: https://babeljs.io/repl#

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get Babel 6 to compile to ES5 javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34747693/how-do-i-get-babel-6-to-compile-to-es5-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#browser_compatibility) is not suppported for IE-11. Try to replicate that using a loop since you are using map anyways.

Also instead of [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#browser_compatibility) you can use normal functions.

```
let dictionary = {};
tempGroups[tempKey].forEach(
function(x) {
 dictionary[x.ID] =  x.Value; 
});
```