# Output of babel : remove arrow functions in a node module

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

I have an issue with my generated webpack bundle on IE11.
I have check the bundle and it is due to some arrow functions.

It come from a node_module package : lite-id

My webpack config :

```
var config = {
    devtool: 'source-map', 
    entry: ["babel-polyfill", APP_DIR + '/index.js'],
    output: {
        path: BUILD_DIR,
        filename: 'BundleNodeJs.js',
        libraryTarget: "umd",    
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.css', '.scss'],
        symlinks: false
    },
    [...]
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules|bower_components/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                options: {
                    presets: ['env', 'react', 'stage-2']
                }
            },
        ]
    }
};
```

What is the good way to transpile arrow functions to regular functions in this node module ?

Comment: Try targetting ES5?

Comment: I tried... this is the same

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34404496/webpack-not-converting-es6-to-es5

Comment: presets: ['env', 'es2015', 'react', 'stage-2'] does not change anything

Comment: Did you install babel-preset-es2015?

Comment: yes, i have installed this preset

Comment: Maybe the problem is this line => exclude: /node_modules|bower_components/ ?

Comment: try adding .js to the test as well.

Comment: Including node_modules in the transpilation solved a similar problem for me.

Comment: Having similar issue with an npm package. I am not able to solve it

Answer (score 0):

If you know for sure `lite-id` is the culprint you could try to exclude `node_modules` except `lite-id` ex: `exclude: /node_modules(?!\/lite-id)/`
In doing so you will transpile `lite-id` along with your code - I think.

Hope it helps!