# Once msw-storybook-addon added, I get Unexpected charachter '#' in node_modules/../Emitter.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, storybook, msw

I want to use my mock servers for my stories. The Storybook runs perfectly. Once I go through the steps of adding `msw-storybook-addon` and set up my `preview.js` from [here](https://storybook.js.org/addons/msw-storybook-addon) and [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/using-storybook-and-mock-service-worker-for-mocked-api-responses/) (preview.js is different in these two resources, I tried both), and I run

```
start-storybook -p 9009 -s public
```

I get the error below:

```
    ERROR in ./node_modules/strict-event-emitter/lib/Emitter.js 14:4
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#' (14:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|  */
| class Emitter {
>     #events;
|     #maxListeners;
|     #hasWarnedAboutPotentialMemortyLeak;
 @ ./node_modules/strict-event-emitter/lib/index.js 17:13-33
 @ ./node_modules/msw/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/mocks/browser.ts
 @ ./.storybook/preview.js
 @ ./.storybook/preview.js-generated-config-entry.js
 @ multi ./node_modules/@storybook/core-client/dist/esm/globals/polyfills.js ./node_modules/@storybook/core-client/dist/esm/globals/globals.js ./node_modules/webpack-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true&quiet=false&noInfo=undefined ./storybook-init-framework-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/react/dist/esm/client/docs/config-generated-config-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/react/dist/esm/client/preview/config-generated-config-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/preview.js-generated-config-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-interactions/preview.js-generated-config-entry.js ./.storybook/preview.js-generated-config-entry.js ./generated-stories-entry.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/strict-event-emitter/lib/MemoryLeakError.js 5:11
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (5:11)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| exports.MemoryLeakError = void 0;
| class MemoryLeakError extends Error {
>     emitter;
|     type;
|     count;
 @ ./node_modules/strict-event-emitter/lib/index.js 18:13-41
 @ ./node_modules/msw/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/mocks/browser.ts
 @ ./.storybook/preview.js
 @ ./.storybook/preview.js-generated-config-entry.js
 @ multi ./node_modules/@storybook/core-client/dist/esm/globals/polyfills.js ./node_modules/@storybook/core-client/dist/esm/globals/globals.js ./node_modules/webpack-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true&quiet=false&noInfo=undefined ./storybook-init-framework-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/react/dist/esm/client/docs/config-generated-config-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/react/dist/esm/client/preview/config-generated-config-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/preview.js-generated-config-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-interactions/preview.js-generated-config-entry.js ./.storybook/preview.js-generated-config-entry.js ./generated-stories-entry.js
Child HtmlWebpackCompiler:
                          Asset      Size               Chunks  Chunk Names
    __child-HtmlWebpackPlugin_0  6.25 KiB  HtmlWebpackPlugin_0  HtmlWebpackPlugin_0
    Entrypoint HtmlWebpackPlugin_0 = __child-HtmlWebpackPlugin_0
    [./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./node_modules/@storybook/core-common/templates/index.ejs] 2.04 KiB {HtmlWebpackPlugin_0} [built]
ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#' (14:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|  */
| class Emitter {
>     #events;
|     #maxListeners;
|     #hasWarnedAboutPotentialMemortyLeak;
    at handleParseError (/Users/akeikha/Documents/code/pharmacy-management-ui/node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack4/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:469:19)
    at /Users/akeikha/Documents/code/pharmacy-management-ui/node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack4/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:503:5
    at /Users/akeikha/Documents/code/pharmacy-management-ui/node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack4/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:358:12
    at /Users/akeikha/Documents/code/pharmacy-management-ui/node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack4/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/Users/akeikha/Documents/code/pharmacy-management-ui/node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack4/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
    at Array.<anonymous> (/Users/akeikha/Documents/code/pharmacy-management-ui/node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack4/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:205:4)
    at Storage.finished (/Users/akeikha/Documents/code/pharmacy-management-ui/node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack4/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:55:16)
    at /Users/akeikha/Documents/code/pharmacy-management-ui/node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack4/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:91:9
    at /Users/akeikha/Documents/code/pharmacy-management-ui/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:123:16
    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (node:internal/fs/read_file_context:68:3)
ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (5:11)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| exports.MemoryLeakError = void 0;
| class MemoryLeakError extends Error {
>     emitter;
|     type;
|     count;
    at handleParseError (/Users/akeikha/Documents/code/pharmacy-management-ui/node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack4/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:469:19)
    at /Users/akeikha/Documents/code/pharmacy-management-ui/node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack4/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:503:5
    at /Users/akeikha/Documents/code/pharmacy-management-ui/node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack4/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:358:12
    at /Users/akeikha/Documents/code/pharmacy-management-ui/node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack4/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/Users/akeikha/Documents/code/pharmacy-management-ui/node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack4/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
    at Array.<anonymous> (/Users/akeikha/Documents/code/pharmacy-management-ui/node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack4/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:205:4)
    at Storage.finished (/Users/akeikha/Documents/code/pharmacy-management-ui/node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack4/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:55:16)
    at /Users/akeikha/Documents/code/pharmacy-management-ui/node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack4/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:91:9
    at /Users/akeikha/Documents/code/pharmacy-management-ui/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:123:16
    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (node:internal/fs/read_file_context:68:3)

WARN Broken build, fix the error above.
WARN You may need to refresh the browser.

info => Loading presets
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

I realized from this error that the file Emmiter.js is using es6 syntax and for some reason, my webpack config doesn't have that loader. So I searched for how to override my webpack config without ejecting from [here](https://marmelab.com/blog/2021/07/22/cra-webpack-no-eject.html). I also looked for the loader that can interpret es6, and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34404496/webpack-not-converting-es6-to-es5). So I added the code below to my `config-override.js`

```
module.exports = function override(config, env) {
  config.module.rules[1].oneOf = config.module.rules[1].oneOf
    .map((one) => {
      if (one.options && one.options.name && one.exclude) {
        one.exclude = [/\.(mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/, /\.html$/, /\.json$/, /\.pdf$/];
      }
      return one;
    })
    .concat([
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        options: { presets: ["es2015"] },
      },
    ]);

  return config;
};
```

And updated my scripts on `package.json`

`yarn start` gets stuck on `Starting the development server...`

I'm not even sure if this is the right solution.
Any ideas what the problem is and what I should do here?

Answer (score 0):

Adding these packages to my `package.json`:

```
"@storybook/builder-webpack5": "6.5.16",
"@storybook/manager-webpack5": "6.5.16",
"webpack" : "5"
```

And these lines to my `main.ts` inside `module.export`

```
core: {
    builder: "@storybook/builder-webpack5"
  },
  docs: {
    autodocs: true
  }
```

resolved the issue.